# Need to format date in "MM-dd-yyyy" in netsuite template

Tags: date, netsuite, date-formatting

I need to format the in template of netSuite without changing the global date format.
As if I am able to change the date format in template then it will work for all the users.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the reference for Freemarker's Date built-ins: https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_date.html

In particular you'll want to look at the `string()` function, which let's you pass in a Date format.

Comment: Thanks eric for your valuable responce .